# How does var work for numbers?

Tags: c#, types, integer, unsigned-integer

I experimented today with how the compiler determines the types for numbers declared as `var`.

```
var a = 255; //Type = int. Value = byte.MaxValue. Why isn't this byte?
var b = 32767; //Type = int. Value = short.MaxValue. Why isn't this short?
var c = 2147483647; //Type = int. Value = int.MaxValue. int as expected.
var d = 2147483648; //Type = uint. Value = int.MaxValue + 1. uint is fine but could have been long?
var e = 4294967296; //Type = long. Value = uint.MaxValue + 1. Type is long as expected.
```

Why is `int` the default for any number that is between `Int32.MinValue` and `Int32.MaxValue`?

Wouldn't it be better to use the smallest possible data type to save memory?
(I understand that these days memory is cheap, but still, saving memory isn't that bad especially if it's so easy to do).

If the compiler did use the smallest data type, and if you had a variable with 255 and knew that later on you would want to store a value like 300, then the programmer could just declare it `short` instead of using `var`.

Why is `var d = 2147483648` implicitly `uint` and not `long`?

Seems as though the compiler will always try and use a 32 bit integer if it can, first signed, then unsigned, then `long`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Seems as though the compiler will always try and use a 32 bit integer if it can, first signed, then unsigned, then long.

That is exactly right. C# Language Specification explains that it tries to pick an integral type that uses the smallest possible number of bytes to represent integer literal with no suffix. Here is the explanation from the language specification:

> To permit the smallest possible `int` and `long` values to be written as decimal integer literals, the following two rules exist:
>
> - When a *decimal-integer-literal* with the value `2147483648` and no *integer-type-suffix* appears as the token immediately following a unary minus operator token, the result is a constant of type `int` with the value `−2147483648`. In all other situations, such a *decimal-integer-literal* is of type `uint`.
> - When a *decimal-integer-literal* with the value `9223372036854775808` and no *integer-type-suffix* or the *integer-type-suffix* `L` or `l` appears as the token immediately following a unary minus operator token, the result is a constant of type `long` with the value `−9223372036854775808`. In all other situations, such a *decimal-integer-literal* is of type `ulong`.

Note that the language specification mentions your `var d = ...` example explicitly, requiring the result to be of type `uint`.

Comment: I wonder why out of byte, short, int, uint, long, ulong, they decided to only use int/uint and long/ulong?

Comment: @Backwards_Dave I think they did it for practicality. Typically `int` and `uint` are the fastest types for integer operations. Arithmetical operations on `byte` and `short` usually perform the operation on `int`, and then truncate it back to fit in the original type. If C# were to use this rule for `short`s and `byte`s, things like `for (var i = 0 ; ... )` would end up generating pretty inefficient code.

Comment: Yes you're right. @Evk provided a good example in the question's comments.